# Visual Studio 2010 Express Resources cache refresh

Tags: visual-studio, caching, refresh

I loaded icon to project in Visual Studio 2010 Express, rebuided project and release exe file of my project has correct icon I loaded.

Then I changed icon little bit after a while and I reloaded changed icon to project but icon was still the old one. I tried to rebuild, delete suo and user files. Nothing works.

Any idea how to refresh / reload icon changed to project?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Build>Clean Solution
2. Build>Rebuild Solution

Comment: it seems there is no such thing as Build>Clean in express version of 2010 hmm

Comment: If you have Express 2010 version try this : http://vicidi.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/enabling-clean-solution-option-in-visual-basic-2010-express/

Comment: this is good but it also didn't show up. I found solution for it finally

Answer (score 0):

Finally this worked for me:

1. Tools\Customize
2. Commands tab
3. Menu bar -> Build
4. Add Command (Build -> Clean Solution)
5. Select the Clean Solution command
6. Put the command where you want it

Solution found here: [http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/...](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/csharp/csharpide.aspx?ID=443bf510-0ff6-4c9c-a6f6-4bcdb587d285)